# Assigning value to array but value doesn't change?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
if (x % 2 == 0) ^ (y % 2 == 1) ^ (z % 2 == 0) {
    grid_box.weights[x][y][x] = 1.0;
    assert_eq!(grid_box.weights[x][y][x], 1.0);
} else {
    grid_box.weights[x][y][z] = 0.0;
    assert_eq!(grid_box.weights[x][y][x], 0.0); // Assertion failed, 1.0 != 0.0
}
```

However, the second assertion fails even though I assigned the grid position to zero in the very previous line. Further experimentation shows that the previous value in the grid seems to make a difference for what the new value should be, even though assignment should override the value entirely.

Comment: “I'm assuming this is a bug in the rust compiler” never assume a beginner would find a bug in a compiler.

Comment: I had been staring at this for a long time, so I "thought" I had exhausted all other options. Anyway, I'll vote to close my own question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, you assign to `grid_box.weights[x][y][z]` and read from `grid_box.weights[x][y][x]`. Replace the `z` with `x`.

Comment: Happens to everyone!